# NextJS API route conflict

Tags: api, routes, next.js

I have been transitioning to NextJS from CRA. I'm re-implementing authentication using SSR, and I would like to use NextJS built-in API routes to set `HTTPOnly` cookies.

There is a weird problem where my backend base URL is `https://somesite.com/api` and my frontend's - `https://somesite.com/`. This means that NextJS built-in API routes will be in conflict with my own backend.

I have been researching online and couldn't find any way on changing routing in NextJS, and I don't want to change base URL of my backend, since there are other services depending on it.

Has anyone had the same issue? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try deleting the API directory from the pages folder. This will remove the API route.

Answer (score 1):

Try next.js rewrite

Rewrites allow you to map an incoming request path to a different destination path. [Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites)

Check Live Example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-rewrite

If Path is /api it'll point to JSON placeholder APIs.(ex. **/api/todos**)

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/:slug*',
        destination: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/:slug*'
      }
    ];
  }
};
```